# how to load Json to flutter listview

Tags: json, listview, flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm developing a flutter app where I have to show in a listView the data on the database.

I get the data in JSON format.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": “1”,
            "testo": "Fare la spesa",
            "stato": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": “2”,
            "testo": "Portare fuori il cane",
            "stato": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": “3”,
            "testo": “jhon”,
            "stato": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I don't load the data, I can't understand how to do it.

I should read 'Data' with an array but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do it?

Thanks for your help.

PS. I tried [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) tutorial

**Main.dart**

```
Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('http://simone.fabriziolerose.it/index.php/Hello/dispdataflutter');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON.
    return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

class Post {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Post({ this.id, this.title, this.body});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(

      id: json['id'],
      title: json['testo'],
      body: json['stato'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp(post: fetchPost()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Post> post;

  MyApp({Key key, this.post}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
            future: post,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather return List of Post from fetchPost(), like below :

```
Future<List<Post>> fetchPost() async {
  final response = await http.get('http://simone.fabriziolerose.it/index.php/Hello/dispdataflutter');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  List responseList = json.decode(response.body);
  return responseList.map((data)=>Post.fromJson(data)).toList();
  } else {
  // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
  throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```

and use **ListView.builder** instead like this

```
List<Post> post;

child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: post.length,
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return ListAdapter(
       id: post[index].id,
       title: post[index].title,
       body: post[index].body
       );
    },
  )
```